# NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData produces incompatible conversion warning/error

Tags: ios, objective-c, serialization, plist

I'm trying to read in data from a plist, using this code:

```
NSString *error;    
NSData * tempData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Data.plist"];
NSDictionary *temp = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:tempData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 error:&error];
```

It kicks out a warning/error stating:

> "Incompatible integer to pointer conversion sending 'int' to parameter of type 'NSPropertyListFormat' (aka 'unsigned int *').

I've no idea what's going on. I chose the NSPropertyListXMLFormat_v1_0 from the code-hinting choices.

Also, I can't find the rationale for this in the documentation so far: why do you have to declare a pointer variable for "error", and then use "&error" as the argument for error:. What is the ampersand for?

Answer (score 31, accepted):

When you're trying to *read* data using `NSPropertyListSerialization`, you don't specify a format: You either pass in NULL, or pass the memory address of a variable.

```
NSError *error;    
NSData * tempData = [[NSData alloc] initWithContentsOfFile:@"Data.plist"];
NSPropertyListFormat plistFormat;
NSDictionary *temp = [NSPropertyListSerialization propertyListWithData:tempData options:NSPropertyListImmutable format:&plistFormat error:&error];
```

The ampersand means "the address in memory where this variable is stored" – by using it, you're giving the method the ability to write to that memory location, and replace the original content of the variable. Both `plistFormat` and (potentially) `error` will contain something new after this method is called: `plistFormat` will tell *you* what format the plist was in, as opposed to the other way around, and `error` (which should be of class `NSError`) will tell you about any errors that were encountered.

Comment: Ohh, I see. In the Property List Programming Guide, Apple describes using this Objective-C method to read the data, but the Quick Start code sample was a little more complex, and I missed this. Thanks very much.